# How to prevent adding same elements twice from one array to another?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**This is my function for adding all elements from array one to array two:**

```
    function addAll() {
        var mList = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(vm.feeds))
        for (var i = 0; i < mList.length; i++) {
            mList[i].is_selected = false;
            vm.rationList.push(mList[i]);
        }
        vm.feeds = [];
        vm.rationListSafe = vm.rationList;
            if(vm.feeds.length == 0){
                vm.currentPageMaster++;
                vm.isPage = true;
                vm.disableScroll = true;
                getFeedsByTeam(vm.selectedTeam);
        }

    }
```

From array **vm.feeds** i add elements to array **vm.rationList**. Is there any way I can prevent adding same elements twice?

Comment: You can check if element exists using `vm.rationList.includes(mList[i])` before pushing into the array.

Comment: I tried it, didn't help me..

Comment: Post that you tried. Update your question.

Comment: You are pushing objects into the array, you need to have some check on particular property.

Answer (score 0):

Consider `Set` constructor. It generates an array of unique values
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set